# Unity android front camera

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, camera, front-camera

how could i change this code to access front cam, currently it shows me back cam.? I have tried some different things, but doesn't seem to be working.

```
    if (isLocalPlayer)
    {
        if (this.gameObject.name == "Player 1") {
            WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture ();
            Player1Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
            Player1Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
            Player1Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
            webcamTexture.Play ();
        } else if (this.gameObject.name == "Player 2") {
            WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture ();
            Player2Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
            Player2Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
            Player2Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
            webcamTexture.Play ();
        } else if (this.gameObject.name == "Player 3") {
            WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture ();
            Player3Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
            Player3Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
            Player3Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
            webcamTexture.Play ();
        } else if (this.gameObject.name == "Player 4") {
            WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture ();
            Player4Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
            Player4Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
            Player4Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
            webcamTexture.Play ();
        } else {
            Debug.Log ("All slots full!");
            GameObject.Destroy (this);
            Network.Disconnect ();
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you have currently creates a WebcamTexture from the default device, as you are using the constructor without any parameters which passes a null string for the **deviceName**.

If you check the [WebCamTexture documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture-ctor.html), it lists a constructor that you can provide a **deviceName**. Now, all you have to do is to:

1. Determine the *deviceName* for the front camera.
2. Use the *deviceName* for the front camera while you are creating your WebCamTexture object.

You can query the device names for the available cameras as follows:

```
var webCamDevices = WebCamTexture.devices;
foreach(var camDevice in webCamDevices){ 
    Debug.Log(camDevice.name);
}
```

Also, the [isFrontFacing](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamDevice-isFrontFacing.html) property of WebCamDevice would also help to query whether the camera you are using is the front camera. Therefore, a naive way of making sure that *the first* front-facing camera that is found will be used for your case would be:

```
if (isLocalPlayer)
{
    string frontCamName = null;
    var webCamDevices = WebCamTexture.devices;
    foreach(var camDevice in webCamDevices){ 
        if(camDevice.isFrontFacing){
            frontCamName = camDevice.name;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (this.gameObject.name == "Player 1") {
        WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture (frontCamName);
        Player1Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
        Player1Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
        Player1Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
        webcamTexture.Play ();
    } else if (this.gameObject.name == "Player 2") {
        WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture (frontCamName);
        Player2Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
        Player2Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
        Player2Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
        webcamTexture.Play ();
    } else if (this.gameObject.name == "Player 3") {
        WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture (frontCamName);
        Player3Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
        Player3Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
        Player3Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
        webcamTexture.Play ();
    } else if (this.gameObject.name == "Player 4") {
        WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture (frontCamName);
        Player4Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
        Player4Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().texture = webcamTexture;
        Player4Image.GetComponent<RawImage> ().material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
        webcamTexture.Play ();
    } else {
        Debug.Log ("All slots full!");
        GameObject.Destroy (this);
        Network.Disconnect ();
    }
}
```

Note that, by removing the **break** statement, you will use the front-facing camera that is listed last. Also, it would be a good practice to make *frontCamName* a private property and initialize it in the Start() function.